# How to get the value of an object ID stored in a variable - in python

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a schoolID variable that is an Object. This is what prints out to the console when I print it:

```
school._id
Out[60]: 
0    5ca588639d83cb7261b73231
Name: _id, dtype: object
```

However, in order for my function to work, I need it to be a string. So at the moment I am having to create another variable and type in the string value myself. Below is my function currently:

```
fun = '5ca588639d83cb7261b73231'
update_this = Example.query.filter_by(_id=fun).first()
```

I want to be able to to use the schoolID variable in the function like this:

```
update_this = Example.query.filter_by(_id=schoolID).first()
```

I have tried converting the object to a string using the str function, but that creates the whole object as a string, rather than just the ID number that I need, see below:

```
str(school._id)
Out[59]: '0    5ca588639d83cb7261b73231\nName: _id, dtype: object'
```

Does anyone know how I can get just the '5ca588639d83cb7261b73231' part of the object saved into a variable so I can use it in my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`school._id` is a series, hence your problem. You can quickly fix by `school._id.iloc[0]` if you are sure the required id is the first one in the series. Consider keeping `school._id` as a `str` instead of `pd.Series`.

Comment: Thanks so much @xletmjm for the quick response. Ok, I shall try that. It's a series because i download it from mongo with all of a schools data in at a time like name, address etc. The ID is the only variable I am using in this case, so it will always only contain one ID for the school I'm doing at that point. How would I change it to a float though?

Comment: No problem, consider accepting the answer on the left hand with a tickmark. To change to float, `school._id = float(school._id.iloc[0])` in a for loop for all schools. Perhaps add `assert len(school._id) == 1` in the loop to make sure that the series is always having only one value. `float` will fail in your case because it's a string, so just keep it as it is; i.e. ```for school in schools: assert len(school_id) == 1 school._id = str(school._id.iloc[0])``` with appropriate indentation of course.